# Not of the expected type in Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm writing a program that takes a list, and replaces all elements (whether it's an atom, a cons, or a list), with "X." So, if I were to evaluate my function with:

```
((A B) (C . D) E))
```

it would return

```
((X X) (X . X) X))
```

However, I keep getting "X is not of the expected type LIST" error when trying to evaluate my function. I don't understand why, though. I'm using Allegro Common Lisp Express edition under Windows. What am I doing wrong?

```
(defun exify (lst)
  (exify-aux lst nil))

(defun exify-aux (lst acc)
  (if (null lst)
      acc
    (if (atom (car lst))
        (append 'x acc)
      (if (consp (car lst))
          (append (cons 'x 'x) acc)
        (if (listp (car lst))
            (append (exify-aux (car lst) nil) acc)
          (if (eq (car lst) nil)
              (append nil acc))))))

  (exify-aux (cdr lst) acc))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of dead code in your code and ulimately it's an infinite loop.

```lisp
(defun exify-aux (lst acc)
  ;; This whole block if, correct, doesn't amount to any result
  (if (null lst)
      acc
    (if (atom (car lst))
        (append 'x acc)
      (if (consp (car lst))
          (append (cons 'x 'x) acc)
        (if (listp (car lst))
            (append (exify-aux (car lst) nil) acc)
          (if (eq (car lst) nil)
              (append nil acc))))))

  ;; This is the tail call and it's called unconditionally
  (exify-aux (cdr lst) acc))
```

You need to be more intimate with `cons`.

```lisp
(defun exify (tree)
  (cond ((null tree) nil)
        ((atom tree) 'x)
        (t (cons (exify (car tree)) 
                 (exify (cdr tree))))))
```

When you are you might want to do higher order functions:

```lisp
(defun exify (tree) 
  (accumulate-tree tree  
                   (lambda (_) 'x) ; replaces all non nil leafs with x
                   #'cons          ; copies branches 
                   nil))           ; copies empty leafs
```

accumualte-tree can be defined like this:

```lisp
(defun accumulate-tree (tree term combiner null-value)
  (labels ((rec (tree)
             (cond ((null tree) null-value)
                   ((atom tree) (funcall term tree))
                   (t (funcall combiner (rec (car tree)) 
                                        (rec (cdr tree)))))))
    (rec tree)))
```

Answer (score 2):

`(append 'x acc)`

How should that work? Append takes lists. `x` is a symbol.

Also, what is the purpose of `(append nil acc)`? Appending empty lists does nothing useful. `(append '() '() '() '())` is just `()`.

Comment: It was my understanding that append would be able to work with symbols. What else could I use to append a symbol to the list acc?

Comment: @OrangeCalx01  Why was that your understanding? Append appends lists. `x`is not a list. Why should that work? The documentation for `append`: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_append.htm#append
is there something about symbols?

Comment: @OrangeCalx01: append lists. Make a list with a symbol. See also the function `cons` for the function you might be looking for...

Comment: Using cons could work, but that makes the new list in reversed order. Nothing says I can't reverse the list at the end of processing though!

Comment: @OrangeCalx01: explain the difference between `(append (list 'x) foo)` and `(cons 'x foo)`. ;-)

Comment: Using cons works, however now I'm getting a stack overflow. I've traced the function, and it seems to get stuck in endless calls whenever (exify nil nil) is called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99633/discussion-between-orangecalx01-and-rainer-joswig).

Comment: @OrangeCalx01: You get an infinite loop because you call `exify-aux` every time again at the last line.